# PHP array json_encode array object to Javascript String

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, react-native

The data received from php api with axios.post is seen as a string as a result. PHP array is returned in object by json_encode and sent as an answer. The received value is supposed to be a Javascript Array, but it comes as String. So I can't use it. How can I fix this problem?

```html
<?php
$price = array();
foreach ($liste as $key => $row) {
    $price[$key] = isset($row['fiyat']) ? $row['fiyat'] : 0;
}
array_multisort($price, SORT_ASC, $liste);

foreach ($liste as $k => $v) {
    if ($v['fiyat'] == 0 || empty($v)) {
        unset($liste[$k]);
    }
}
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$liste = array_values($liste);
file_put_contents("/tmp/scanner.txt",json_encode($liste));

echo json_encode($liste);


?>
```

```js
 Axios.post("http://www.otelscanner.com/inc/snap_craw.php", { request: "mobile", tarih: "01-07-2020", tarih2: "04-07-2020", crawler: 14, url: "http://www.saratour.com/sunmelia-beach-resort-hotel-spa" }, {
        }).then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
```

[image: Re]

Comment: `JSON.parse(response.data)`?

Comment: response.data String bro. I tried also gived me error ; Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse

Comment: There isn't an `o` in position 1 in the data in your image...

Comment: it looks normal if I copy and use the data. but I have to return to array object

https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=local.xahono&right=cloud.9e06a160209f4137b2c440b03a08baf4

Comment: I think the characters \ t \ r \ n don't recognize the javascript. but i could nt clear with javascript